# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

No puedo acceder a buscar un usuario ya que me sale el error de **split**.

Este es mi código:

views.py

```
def buscar_usuario(request):
    from django.utils import simplejson

    busqueda = request.GET.get('busqueda')

    busquedas = busqueda.split(' ')
    resultados_nombre = Usuario.objects.all()
    #Filtro por cada palabra de busqueda
    for b in busquedas:
        resultados_nombre = resultados_nombre.filter(nombre__icontains = b)

    resultados_cedula = Usuario.objects.all()
    #Filtro por cada palabra de busqueda
    for b in busquedas:
        resultados_cedula = resultados_cedula.filter(nombre__icontains = b)



    #Maximo un resultado:
    resultados_cedula = resultados_cedula[:1];
    if resultados_cedula.exists() :
        resultados = resultados_cedula;
    else:
        resultados = resultados_nombre[:1];

    respuesta = []
    for u in resultados:
        respuesta.append({'nombre': u.nombre, 'cedula':u.cedula, 'carnet':u.carnet, 'saldo':u.saldo_str()});


    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(respuesta), content_type = 'application/javascript; charset=utf8')
```

Y el error es:

```
Internal Server Error: /sistemacaja/buscar_usuario
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\us\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\us\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\us\sistema_ventas_ceic_master\ventas_app\views.py", line 473, in buscar_usuario
    busquedas = busqueda.split(":")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
[16/Nov/2018 17:50:16] "GET /sistemacaja/buscar_usuario HTTP/1.1" 500 89277
```

Comment: El error indica que la variable `busqueda` sobre la que intentas el `split()`, tiene el valor `None`. Más allá de eso no te puedo ayudar y debes depurar tu aplicación (ya sea con un depurador o intercalando `print()` aquí y allá para ver los valores de las variables) y averiguar por qué vale `None` cuando tú creías que debía valer otra cosa.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` hace referencia a que `busqueda` está vacío.

Comment: Y por cierto que el _stacktrace_ mostrando el error no corresponde al mismo código que has pegado, pues el error muestra que a `split()` le habías pasado la cadena `":"`, mientras que en tu código le pasas un espacio.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que en esta línea no se está recibiendo ningún parámetro `búsqueda` por eso la variable tiene el valor None , puedes añadir una coma y dos comillas simples de esta manera si no existe siempre cogerá el valor '' y ya no te dará el error en el Split pero te recomiendo que revises tu plantilla para comprobar que estás enviado el parámetro correctamente

```
busqueda = request.GET.get('busqueda', '')
```